# How to sort the 'joined' xsl nodeset

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this (simplified) XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<LENEX version="3.0">
  <MEETS>
    <MEET name="British Gas Champs 2012">
      <SESSIONS>
        <SESSION number="1" name="Session 1" course="LCM" date="2012-07-22">
          <EVENTS>
            <EVENT eventid="104" number="104" gender="M" round="PRE" order="4">
              <SWIMSTYLE distance="100" stroke="BACK" name="Boys 14 Yrs 100m Backstroke" />
              <AGEGROUPS>
                <AGEGROUP agegroupid="1" name="14 Yrs Age Group">
                  <RANKINGS>
                    <RANKING place="3" resultid="1" />
                  </RANKINGS>
                </AGEGROUP>
              </AGEGROUPS>
            </EVENT>
          </EVENTS>
        </SESSION>
        <SESSION number="2" name="Session 2" course="LCM" date="2012-07-22">
          <EVENTS>
            <EVENT eventid="207" number="207" gender="M" round="PRE" order="7">
              <SWIMSTYLE distance="100" stroke="FREE" name="Boys 14 Yrs 100m Freestyle"/>
              <AGEGROUPS>
                <AGEGROUP agegroupid="1" name="14 Yrs Age Group">
                  <RANKINGS>
                    <RANKING place="1" resultid="2"/>
                  </RANKINGS>
                </AGEGROUP>
              </AGEGROUPS>
            </EVENT>
          </EVENTS>
        </SESSION>
      </SESSIONS>
      <CLUBS>
        <CLUB name="Aberdeen ASC" region="X" type="CLUB">
          <ATHLETES>
            <ATHLETE athleteid="1169" lastname="Butt" firstname="Suleman">
              <RESULTS>
                <RESULT resultid="1" eventid="104" swimtime="00:01:01.18"/>
                <RESULT resultid="2" eventid="207" swimtime="00:00:53.06"/>
              </RESULTS>
            </ATHLETE>
          </ATHLETES>
        </CLUB>
      </CLUBS>
    </MEET>
  </MEETS>
</LENEX>
```

and this stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">

<xsl:variable name="session" select="/LENEX/MEETS/MEET/SESSIONS/SESSION" />
<xsl:variable name="athlete" select="/LENEX/MEETS/MEET/CLUBS/CLUB/ATHLETES/ATHLETE" />

<!-- variable for testing/debugging-->
<xsl:variable name="athlno" select="1169" />
 <!--<xsl:param name="evno" />-->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="$athlete" />
        </body> 
    </html>
</xsl:template>

  <!-- find the results (@resultid) for athleteid in $athlno  -->
<xsl:template match="ATHLETE[@athleteid]">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="self::ATHLETE[@athleteid = $athlno]/RESULTS">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::RESULTS/RESULT">
      <!-- these 'sorts' works -->
   <!--   <xsl:sort select="@resultid" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="@eventid" order="descending"/> -->
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

  <!-- create $res1 $stim1 variables to pass to 'SESSIONS' node -->
  <xsl:template match="RESULT">
    <xsl:variable name="res1" ><xsl:value-of select="@resultid"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="stim1" ><xsl:value-of select="@swimtime"/></xsl:variable>
    <tr>
      <!--join to 'SESSIONS' node -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$session/EVENTS/EVENT">
   <!-- this xsl:sort doesn't work   
   <xsl:sort select="@number" data-type="text" order="descending"/>-->
      <xsl:with-param name="res2"  select="$res1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="stim2"  select="$stim1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EVENT">
      <xsl:param name="res2" />
      <xsl:param name="stim2" />
      <xsl:for-each select="child::AGEGROUPS/AGEGROUP/RANKINGS/RANKING[@resultid = $res2]">
        <!-- this xsl:sort doesn't work   -->
        <xsl:sort select="@place" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@place"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="../../../../@round = 'TIM'">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>HDW
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="../../../../@round = 'PRE'">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>Heat
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="../../../../@round = 'SEM'">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>Semi-F
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="../../../../@round = 'FIN'">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>Final
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>n/a
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="../../../../SWIMSTYLE/@name" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring($stim2,4)"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="../../../../@number" /><br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I only seem to be able to sort by the main nodeset ie RESULTS/RESULT/@resultid or RESULTS/RESULT/eventid.  I would like to sort the results of a 'join' by EVENT/SWIMSTYLE/@stroke, EVENT/SWIMSTYLE/@distance and EVENT/@round.  I am limited to XSLT 1.0. What I've tried is commented in the XSLT above.
The output I'm looking for is ...

```
3 Final Boys 14 Yrs 100m Backstroke 01:00.83 269 
3 Heat Boys 14 Yrs 100m Backstroke 01:01.18 104 
3 Semi-F Boys 14 Yrs 100m Backstroke 01:00.66 156 
1 Final Boys 14 Yrs 100m Freestyle 00:52.61 363 
1 Heat Boys 14 Yrs 100m Freestyle 00:53.06 207 
1 Semi-F Boys 14 Yrs 100m Freestyle 00:53.56 259 
1 Final Boys 14 Yrs 200m Freestyle 01:53.34 555 
1 Heat Boys 14 Yrs 200m Freestyle 01:57.29 402 
1 Semi-F Boys 14 Yrs 200m Freestyle 01:55.23 454 
1 Final Boys 14 Yrs 400m Freestyle 04:03.46 351 
1 Heat Boys 11/14 Yrs 400m Freestyle 04:09.46 301
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Try to post your code so we can help you ;-)

Comment: What does your desired output look like?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments.  I'm applying the stylesheet to the snip of XML. The full XML is too large to post.  The portion of the XML I've posted will only produce two of the lines of the expected output (in a debugger).  I can't work out how to sort on the attributes I've listed.  Everything I've tried (see comments in style sheet) doesn't sort the output. maybe I need to post more of the XML.  is there a way to attach the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few keys will help you build paths to your sort attributes:

```
<!-- Map from @resultid to EVENT -->
<xsl:key name="result-event" match="//EVENT" use="descendant::RANKING/@resultid"/>
<!-- Map from @resultid to RANKING -->
<xsl:key name="ranking" match="//RANKING" use="@resultid"/>
```

Then, when templating the RESULT elements for an ATHLETE, you can reference the sort attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ATHLETE"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ATHLETE">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="RESULTS/RESULT">
        <xsl:sort select="key('result-event', @resultid)/SWIMSTYLE/@stroke"/>
        <xsl:sort select="key('result-event', @resultid)/SWIMSTYLE/@distance" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:sort select="key('result-event', @resultid)/@round"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RESULT">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('ranking', @resultid)/@place"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('result-event', @resultid)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@swimtime"/>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EVENT">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@round"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="SWIMSTYLE/@name" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="../../@number" />
</xsl:template>
```

You can adjust the sort order for rounds by using a lookup table to map the `@round` key to an arbitrary surrogate key.

Comment: just the answer I was hoping for.  I've up voted your post but I'm sorry - because I don't have enough 'reputation' yet my vote is not displayed.  many thanks.

Comment: If you feel the answer adequately addresses your question you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check mark next to the score. This too bestows imaginary internet points.

Comment: Thanks for the steer.  I've accepted your response.